# What has happened with apk sizes and zip alignment since Android Studio 3.6?

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk, ndk-build, zipalign

Since I updated to Android Studio 3.6 two things has happened to my release APK:

- It has grown from 60mb to 102mb
- zipalign.exe does not successfully alignment to 4
- My app uses native libraries, and using verbose output from zipalign it seems the .so files are the files which isn't successfully zipaligned.

However, when I inspect the APK from Android Studio, it says that the downloaded size is still 60mb.

It seems something in the release management has changed, but I cannot find any info on what has changed.

1. Does anyone know what has changed?
2. Should I perform some action?

Answer (score 1):

Native libraries packaged uncompressed by default (from AS3.6):
[https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-6-0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#extractNativeLibs)